# Handle Popup? We get white page now

Tags: popup, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, web-testing

How to handle a popup with testcafe?

We press a button and than a popup is opened. In that popup we select something and then the popup is closed again and that info is being used in the main page (which was still open in the background.
The behavior looks something like this: https://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_popup_window_code.cfm

However, when trying this with testcafe the popup is full-sized and doesn't go back to the main page (maybe a relation is lost?)

Any tips?

The button looks something like this in the code:

```
<input type="button" value="Calculate prices" onclick="if(check_fields(tmp_arr) &amp;&amp; check_positive_value_highlight(document.getElementsByName('value')[0], true) &amp;&amp; check_empty_() &amp;&amp; true) { showBig_v2('popup_thingie_cost.asp?formname=getInfo&amp;fieldname11=xx&amp;fieldname5=xx&amp;fieldname6=xx&amp;bgcolor=white&amp;fieldname10=xx&amp;fieldname12=xxx&amp;title=Choose+x+service&amp;footer=YES&amp;vat=NO&amp;default_off=YES&amp;type=xx&amp;fieldname4=xx&amp;fieldname1=xx;xx=&amp;xx=xx&amp;xx=&amp;xx=&amp;xx=&amp;xx=&amp;xx=&amp;xx=&amp;language=EN&amp;xx=&amp;xx=&amp;xx='); }">
```

Answer (score 0):

TestCafe has limited support for popup windows right now, but we are working on the implementation of proper [multiple browser windows support](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/912) and this is in our [Roadmap](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/roadmap/).

UPD: The [Multiple Browser Windows](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/advanced-guides/multiple-browser-windows.html) feature is released in `testcafe@1.11.0`.